# ElixirLS debugger unexpectedly stops when used with Phoenix and VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, elixir, phoenix-framework, elixirls

Trying to debug my Phoenix project in VSCode using ElixirLS.
The launch config is defined as

```
{
  "type": "mix_task",
  "name": "mix phx.server",
  "request": "launch",
  "task": "phx.server",
  "projectDir": "${workspaceRoot}"
}
```

The debugger starts and displays call stack for a fraction of a second but then immediately stops after *"[info] Access TestAppWeb.Endpoint at http://localhost:4000"* (see animated gif below). Has anyone gotten this to work?

Elixir 1.9.1

[image: Debugger stops after launch]

Comment: Seems like this isn't just limited to Phoenix.  You get the same behaviour with a vanilla Elixir project running `mix run`.  Project launches, debugger is attached, then exits.

Comment: did you get it to work?

Comment: I've opened a GitHub issue - https://github.com/JakeBecker/elixir-ls/issues/185

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like this issue is fixed in the fork of ElixirLS at https://github.com/elixir-lsp/elixir-ls .

The original repo doesn't have any commits since 10 Aug 2019, but the fork is pretty active.